# MySQL performance with nested sub query

Tags: mysql

I have two tables messages and members. I tried joining tables without having a nested query but it does not reflect the join on members. So, I initially thought that I could do the following

```
SELECT M1.*, COUNT(M2.emid) AS replies FROM messages M1
LEFT JOIN messages M2 
    ON M2.thread = M1.emid
INNER JOIN members M 
    ON M.meid = M1.emitter
WHERE 
    M1.thread is NULL AND 
    M1.receiver = 2
GROUP BY 
    M1.emid
```

but it does not seem to join the corresponding member. Then I tried this and it gives me the result that I need but I would like to know if there is a way to accomplish the same result using joins without the nested query

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT M1.*, COUNT(M2.emid) AS replies FROM messages M1
    LEFT JOIN messages M2 
        ON M2.thread = M1.emid
    WHERE 
        M1.thread is NULL AND 
        M1.receiver = 2
    GROUP BY 
        M1.emid
) O INNER JOIN members M ON O.receiver = M.meid
```

---

### -- Table structure for table `members`

```
CREATE TABLE `members` (
  `meid` bigint(64) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `mobile` char(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `college` bigint(64) NOT NULL,
  `major` bigint(64) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `oauth` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `confirmed` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `joined` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

---

### -- Table structure for table `messages`

```
CREATE TABLE `messages` (
  `emid` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `emitter` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `receiver` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `thread` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `opened` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `message` blob NOT NULL,
  `timecard` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Why in the broken example is it joining on M1.emitter but in the working example it joining on M1.receiver?

Comment: You don't seem to be using any columns from the members table in the SELECT part your first query -  in the second you select *

Comment: In general you really shouldn't mix aggregate and non-aggregate columns even though MySQL lets you do that. Why are you concerned about eliminating the inner query?

Comment: I am not concerned, I am just trying to find out if there is a better way. That's it!

Comment: Personally I think it would be more straightforward if you just used a scalar  subquery in the `select` list to return the count. Honestly I can't recall whether MySQL supports that but I think it does.

Comment: Can you tell me why  that's a better idea!